# Css normal size of an image field

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am writing a mobile app and I want to set the image size such that if it is on Iphone 5 than the size is X, otherwise, the size is the original size of the image. what I will do is:

```
width: is5? 288: *original size*,
height: is5? 200: *original size*
```

How do I get *original size*? I thought it was "auto" but that did not work, my image is gone that way in the other than 5 iphones.

Comment: Should the image consume the whole width of the screen?

Comment: No, the image has on original size that is fine in most iphones. just in iphone 5 I am changing it. I want that in iphone 5 it will be x and in the others it will stay the same

Comment: you can find the original size in the details of the image

Comment: yeah but I dont want it to be constant, there is a script that handles the images resolution in iphone 7 or iphone X.

Comment: ok. if you place it inside a div and set a `background-size: cover` to the div instead of setting the size?

Comment: Ideally, you should not rely on the size of the image. Setting the size to something specific to one device resolution does not seem to be a good approach. Aim to make it responsive as per different resolution ranges, not as per a device.

Comment: its like that, iphone 5 is an exception per our designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Image Component has a method [getSize](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#getsize). By calling this method you can get the original image size. The retrieved width and height can then be stored in state variables.

Example:

```
// get the original image size and save it
Image.getSize(YOUR_IMAGE_URI, (width, height) => {this.setState({width, height})});
```

and then later you can do:

```
<Image source={{uri: YOUR_IMAGE_URI}} style={{width: is5? 280 : this.state.width, height: is5 ? 200 : this.state.height }} />
```